# How to restore a Bitbucket Server DIY backup restore work with a postgres database?

Tags: linux, debian, database, postgresql, bitbucket.org

I am trying to make the [Bitbucket Server DIY backup](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver0516/using-bitbucket-server-diy-backup-966061910.html) work.
My work is based of the example DIY backup scripts given [here](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/atlassian-bitbucket-diy-backup/src/master/).

I am using the most recent version of bitbucket server on a Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch). My bitbucket installation uses an external postgres 11.5 database.

I managed to configure the backup variables of [bitbucket.diy-backup.vars.sh](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/atlassian-bitbucket-diy-backup/src/master/bitbucket.diy-backup.vars.sh.example) in order to make the backup work.
However, I could not make the [restore script](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/atlassian-bitbucket-diy-backup/src/master/bitbucket.diy-restore.sh) work. The restore script stops at a failed pg_restore command : [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS1Ad.png)

So this fails:

```
pg_restore -U <username> -h localhost --port=5432 -j 5 -d <dbname> -C -Fd /tmp/bitbucket.dyi-restore...
```

"FATAL: password authentication failed for user " is the error I get, as shown in the screenshot. I am not an expert with postgres so I would like some advice to understand why this fails.

I can run the following command to connect to the database successfully if I'm logged in with the database owner user.

```
psql <dbname>
```

I deduce that the database is up and running and that I have access to it. So why does the script fail on the connection to the database ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this command with root privileges, since only the root user would be having permissions to modify or access your database.
Try adding a sudo before the command, or run 'sudo su -' to get the # prompt and run the command as root user.
Hope this helps!